# Is there a built in way to achieve the design pattern of a list item with an action button in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a list (or fake a list using LinearLayouts) that follows the design pattern shown in this image of a list item with an action button to the far right.  (the second list item in the 2 line list)

Is there an easy way to add the action button with that separator bar?

[image: android list view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the basic layout using a horizontal LinearLayout. Add the content view with a weight of 1, and then add the button view with a weight of 0. That will push the button view to the far right. To add that separator, you could just add a basic View between the two with a weight of 0, width of 1dp, and the desired height and margins. Setting the background color of the View determines the color of the separator.

It shouldn't be too difficult. If you want to include it in a ListView, just hide the action button and separator until you're rendering an item that needs it.

**Edit:** Added some clarification

Comment: Thanks, used an empty View and created a style for the divider.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in. You'd need to create a horizontal `LinearLayout` and set the divider (using [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) or after API level 11 - `setShowDividers`, `setDividerDrawable`, `setDividerPadding`). Otherwise, use a third View in the middle.

You'd probably want to have `itemsCanFocus="true"` on the ListView to get reasonable click behaviour (though you will lose the `OnItemClick` callback, you can replicate it with a normal `OnClick` on the horizontal `LinearLayout`).

Comment: Keep in mind that `setShowDividers` is only supported as of API level 11 (Honeycomb).

Comment: Correct, I should add that to the answer. HoloEverywhere has spoiled me. :)

Comment: We didn't use HoloEverywhere, but thinking for the next project I probably will, if it cuts down on API version specific styles.